# Test Significance Between Two Groups (not mean?)

Tags: statistical-significance

I'm conducting my bachelor thesis and I need to do research. This morning I received mail from my supervisor and I'm not quite getting wat he wants me to do. I hope someone can help me.

PS: I will try to keep it as simple as possible.

[image]

My supervisor send me the following: "The other is to compare the  local versus foreign analyst recommendation statistically. For example, for each stock, calculate the difference between CAR_local analyst and CAR_adr analyst. Then report whether the differences are significant"

My expectation is that the Foreign will be significantly higher than the local. What do you suspect I need to perform for kind of test.

PS: I have SPSS and Eviews on my pc.

Every help is much appreciated!

EDIT: My N will be around 300 (so 300 stocks)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like he wants you to run a paired t-test. In SPSS Analyze > compare means > paired t-test.

Comment: This presently reads more like a comment than an answer. At the least, one line answers are normally frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will give this a try and I hope he agrees with this method. Have a nice day sir